# iPad Controls and Locks

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management, parental-controls

Is there a way to lock kids out of settings and the controls for iPads? We have had issues where they change the screens, upgrade to iOS7, lock the device and other problems.

We have a sync cart and I'm just very new to it. We are running iOS 7 and Apple Configurator 1.4

Is there a way to prevent students from setting a lockout code? We don't lock them and that option is left open and they sometimes will lock the ipad forcing us to have to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) includes a feature that allows you to select an app to 'lock' a supervised device to. When supervising a device, you can **Lock to App** and the iPad will be unable to escape from the app. This feature will prevent all hardware buttons from leaving the app (except a hard reset initiated by holding both Home and Power).

[image: Apple Configurator: Lock to App]

<sup>[**Source**: Hands-on: Securing iOS, pwning your kids with Apple Configurator 1.2](http://educationwithinnovation.badnewsracing.net/EducationWithInnovation/Education_Technology_Learning_Summit_files/Securing%20iOS%20pwning%20your%20kids%20with%20Apple%20Configurator%201.2.pdf)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways of doing this:-

- Put the settings app in a folder and remove Applications to be searched from the Spotlight search. Here you can not hide the App as such.
- With Jailbreak you can hide apps from SB Settings, but as there is no Jailbreak you cannot use this right now.
- The settings app can not be restricted as such right now, but you can use the [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12). I haven't used it myself but searching online forums show that this can be used.